# Getting prime numbers between a range

Tags: c#, linq, primes

I have the following code to get the prime numbers between a range of numbers. Is this the best and fastest method?

```
int[] numberCollection = Enumerable.Range(startNum,Count).ToArray<int>();
string primeNumbers = string.Join(",", from number in numberCollection 
                                       where (IsPrime(number)==true)
                                       select number);
```

Where :

- `startNum` is the starting number
- `Count` is the number of numbers in the collection
- `IsPrime` is a method defined as follows:

  ```
    private static bool IsPrime(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < number/2; i++)
            if (number % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
  ```

Comment: This is a very poor way of generating prime numbers within a range in case the range is large. You should try and do more research about the **Sieve of Eratosthenes** [GeeksForGeeks article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only executing this once, it should work fine as is.  If you are going to execute it more than once per century, you should use the **Sieve of Eratosthenes**, as suggested by Somnath Rakshit.

Using the algorithm as described on wikipedia:

```
static class MathExtensions
{
    static public List<int> GetPrimes(int start, int end)
    {
        List<int> res = new List<int>();

        // 1. Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 through n: (2, 3, 4, ..., n).
        int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, end).ToArray();

        // 2. Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
        int idx = 2;
        do
        {
            // If the number is in range, add it to the result
            if (numbers[idx] >= start)
            {
                res.Add(numbers[idx]);
            }

            // 3. Starting from p, enumerate its multiples by counting to n in increments of p, and mark them in the list (these will be 2p, 3p, 4p, ... ; the p itself should not be marked).
            for (var i = idx; i < end; i += idx)
            {
                numbers[i] = 0;
            }

            // 4. Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let p now equal this new number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step 3.
            while (idx < end && numbers[idx] == 0)
            {
                idx++;
            }
        }
        while (idx < end);

        return res;
    }
}
```